# Getting all values from table after grouping by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that contains items with three values Id, RevisionId and Data like this.

```
| Id | RevisionId | Data   |
| 0  | 0          | Value1 |
| 0  | 1          | Value2 |
| 1  | 0          | Value1 |
| 2  | 0          | Value1 |
| 2  | 1          | Value2 |
| 2  | 3          | Value3 |
```

If I want only the Id with the highest RevisionId for each I can make an SQL statement like this.

```
SELECT Id, MAX(RevisionId) AS RevisionId FROM RevisionTable GROUP BY Id
```

But I don't know how to get the Data value connected to that max RevisionId for each Id.

Comment: Yes, I guess i didn't look thoroughly enough.

Comment: If it does, you can accept the duplicate as the answer, and it'll close the question automatically, @Zucchini .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by revisionid desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

`top(1) with ties` also comes to mind:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from mytable t
order by row_number() over(partition by id order by revisionid desc) rn
```